# EF 4.3.1 IMigrationMetadata.Target strings are causing "No logical space left to create more user strings." compile errors

Tags: entity-framework

We've generated ~80 migrations since the release of the 4.3.x version of Entity Framework.  Each time we generate a new migration, EF gens a snapshot of the current model for the IMigrationMetadata.Target property.

Since each migration is adding ~135k characters to our assembly, we are starting to hit critical mass.  We're now receiving a "No logical space left to create more user strings." compiler error.  Combine that w/ the pre-compile views, and you've got a lot of strings.

What's the best long term approach to using EF migrations with a complex model?

Maybe add-migration should be generating these w/ resource files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I have added this issue to our backlog for EF6.

For now, replacing the string with a resource lookup is the best workaround I can think of.

Comment: Note- this has now been fixed as of EF5: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/289

Answer (score 2):

we had the same issue. We are also fix this using moving the generated string into resource:

```
 public sealed partial class RegionalCenterRenameClass : IMigrationMetadata
 { 
  // Skipped code

  string IMigrationMetadata.Target
  {
    get { return Targets.M201207110918331_RegionalCenterRenameClass; }
   }
 }
```

where Targets - is resource file (resx).