# no logical space left to create more user strings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

While trying to compile and debug C# code in Visual Studio I'm hitting this error - "no logical space left to create more user strings". Actually, the code compiles properly, but it crashes with this error while trying to create the executable.

I've looked at [C# compile error: "No logical space left to create more user strings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362635/c-sharp-compile-error-no-logical-space-left-to-create-more-user-strings) and [EF 4.3.1 IMigrationMetadata.Target strings are causing "No logical space left to create more user strings." compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691155/ef-4-3-1-imigrationmetadata-target-strings-are-causing-no-logical-space-left-to) but these don't help here, since they talk about C# code that was generated by some other script/process.

In my case, it's normal C# code that's being compiled/linked and hitting this error.

Can someone please help me figure out how I can debug this issue? What may be causing this problem?

There are a total of about 10 string declarations in my code.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that is causing this error.  Can you make a small sample reproduce the error?

Comment: When it creates the executable it's not just working with your code but also any third party code you have.  I'd look there.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) application to dump out all the strings in your application,from which you will be able to find ,what string is being created multiple times.

Alternatively you may also use Windbg